# Multiple Task.WhenAll termination on the first Exception in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

The following sample code snippet implements the multitasking functionality by reading/processing the content of Web Url sample list `List<string> urls` utilizing `async/await` coding technique (similar to the MSDN demo sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx). For testing purpose, the Url `List<string> urls` contains two erroneous items.

*Listing 1. Error handling in WPF async/await implementation of multiple Tasks*

```
    namespace ProcessTasksAsTheyFinish
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts;
            // sample Url list containing erroneous items
            private List<string> SetUpURLList()
            {
                List<string> urls = new List<string> 
                { 
                    "http://msdn.microsoft.com",
                    "http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx",
                    "error1",
                    "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578028.aspx",
                    "error2",
                    "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404677.aspx",
                    "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730837.aspx"
                };
                return urls;
            }

            public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

            private async void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                resultsTextBox.Clear();
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                try { await AccessTheWebAsync(cts.Token);}
                finally { cts = null; }
            }

            private async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct) {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    // sample list of web addresses
                    List<string> urlList = SetUpURLList();
                    // query to create a collection of Tasks
                    IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery =
                        from url in urlList select ProcessURL(url, client, ct);
                    // run multiple Tasks in async mode
                    await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasksQuery.ToList());
                    resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads complete.";
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException){
                    resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads canceled.";
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    resultsTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
                }
            }

            private async Task<int> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);
                    byte[] urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    resultsTextBox.Text += String.Format("\r\nLength:  {0}", urlContents.Length);
                    return urlContents.Length;
                }
                catch 
                { 
                    //if (cts != null)  cts.Cancel(); 
                    throw; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
// sample output:
// Length:  196315
// Length:  468941
// Length:  158496
// Length:  200790
// Length:  48022
// An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

The output contains length info calculated for the 5 valid Urls and error notification corresponding to the Exception `ex.Message`.

The goal was to modify the functionality in a such way that the first exception  will completely terminate the multitasking execution of the `await Task.WhenAll`. In other words, to implement the sort of "All or Nothing" business logic pertinent to the awaited multiple `Tasks`.

In this example, it's been achieved by adding the following statement to the `Exception` handling block using `CancellationToken` (shown as commented line in Listing 1):

```
if (cts != null)  cts.Cancel();
```

The output text looks as expected, corresponding to `ex.Message`:

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an
>   absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

**EDITED**: I was looking for a simplified implementation of the same  "All or Nothing" functionality (enabling to terminate the entire set of `Tasks` in the `Task.WhenAll` procedure on the first error) without using the `CancellationToken`. As per the insightful comments posted by @Stephen Cleary, there is no any overload "shortcut" option and no better solution (in terms of simplicity) than the current one.

Comment: Questions asking "is it possible" are almost never useful. It's software. You can _always_ write code to do something you can imagine. It's just a question of how much effort you want to put in. And there are always many different ways to achieve the goal. It seems to me that the code you have works, and in fact uses CTS in just the way it was intended to be used. Do you have some _specific_ problem you're trying to solve here? Is there something about using CTS that interferes with correct operation of your program? Please narrow the question if you want an answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've made it utmost clear that the purpose is to simplify the code by eliminating the CancellationToken. It is not just about some "abstract possibility" depending on the amount of time/efforts because the required (simplified) solution may not exist. The CancellationToken seems an overkill for this biz logic; if Exception handler can terminate the Task without Token, then it would be fine. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell There's no overload or anything that provides a shortcut; the code you already have is the best approach.

Comment: @StephenCleary Many thanks for looking into this issue and your insightful comments: the case is clear now. You may post it as the answer and I will accept. Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload that provides this kind of functionality built-in.

In general, automatic cancelling of `CancellationTokenSource` objects is not in the BCL (with the exception of the timeout convenience methods, which automatically cancel based on a timer). If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say that the BCL team feels there's too many differing use cases for these kinds of overloads, so they wouldn't be useful enough to a broad enough audience to be built-in.

Instead, the appropriate solution is to trigger the CTS yourself once any one of the tasks faults, which is what your code is already doing.